# Movilizer - Masterdata references deleted when deleting key?

Tags: mobile, movilizer

Within the Movilizer Product context.

We have a big masterdata customer pool divided in groups G1, G2, G3...

The keys are referenced between the groups key1 is in G2 and G3 for example.

If I delete "key1" (masterdatadelete). Will it be deleted from the pool and all its references? (disapearing completelly from any movelet referencing G2 or G3).

Comment: What exactly is your masterdatadelete? Could you upload an example with your request (.mxml file?). You can have some examples here: https://devtools.movilizer.com/confluence/display/DOC21/Masterdata+Create+and+Upload

Comment: Yes, an example would be like this: 

`<masterdataPoolUpdate pool="P1">
  <update key="key1" group="G2"><description>key1Desc</description>
  </update>
  <reference key="key1" group="G3" />
</masterdataPoolUpdate>`

"key1" is on G2 and G3. A delete on "key1" removes all references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this depends on your specific delete command.

```
    <delete key="key1" group="G2" /> <!-- deletes from G2 only --> 
    <delete key="key1" /> <!-- deletes from all groups -->
```

Comment: Hmmm I just figured .... you can not delete key1 from group G2 if that is the original Masterdata entry. It might help if you can post your original code here @Lucke

Comment: Yes, as stated above if I have:
`<masterdataPoolUpdate pool="P1">
  <update key="key1" group="G2"><description>key1Desc</description>
  </update>
  <reference key="key1" group="G3" />
</masterdataPoolUpdate>`

And I send a delete like this:

`<delete key="key1" />` does it remove all references or do I have to send a delete for each reference and then the "master entry"?

Comment: The delete without a group deletes the original one and all its references